# why is the internal storage mmc and not sd?

Tags: storage

I’ve been researching the difference bewteen sd and mmc after noticing that openwrt (and other distributions) name the internal storage that contains the system as mmcblk and other disks that live in external sd card readers as sd.

The thing that is confusing me is that the internal memory is also an sd card. So why does the system say that it is mmc?  Is it because the reader is an mmc reader or is it some kind of emulation to make it compatible with the rest of the system?

Comment: `sd` are `scsi` disks and are probably using `scsi` over `usb`. Whereas `mmc` is using a direct driver and so are named `mmcblk...`

Comment: @Bib hmm…. from what I’ve  read, sd means secure disk, and in linux systems is often expanded to read ‘standard disk’ in linux.  mmc stands for multimedia card.  there are technical differences too.

Comment: I am looking at it from a device name point of view ... `/dev/sdX` & `/dev/mmcblkX`, Where the `sd` means `scsi disk`

Comment: Why is the SD card is referred to as mmc when most of what ive read about sd and mmc is that you can use an mmc card in an sd card reader, but not an sd card in an mmc reader.  So how come this is possible in the openwrt linux on raspberry pi set up?  Ive seen mmc hats for sale on various website that look like they take an sd card, so i guess the internal card reader on the pi is actually an mmc reader.  But how is linux able to read this if the sd card format is not backwards compatible with mmc?

Comment: I've told you, where it uses the `scsi` protocols, usually over `usb`, it will have a device name of `sdX`, whereas, if it uses the `mmc` protocols, it will be referred to as `mmcblkX`. What the device actually is matters little. All that matters is how it is connected to the system. On my RPi, it uses an `sd` card in the `mmc` socket and is referred to as `/dev/mmvblkX`. If i was to connect that via `usb`, then it would be referred to as `/dev/sdX`. That mmc card, is an sd card, but that sd does not refer to the device type name.

Comment: Thanks.   Final question (may be off topic, if so please re-direct me): why do some people (for example you) answer a post as a comment rather than an answer?  Does it affect your rating on the forum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/dev/sdX` indeed once meant *SCSI disk*, but nowadays it covers anything with a SCSI-like interface, including SATA, USB storage and even old PATA when libata drivers are used. Some actually have suggested reinterpreting it just as *storage device*.

The MMC memory card specification was introduced in 1997, and SD cards were introduced in 1999 as an improvement over the MMC specification. So you can think of MMC as the "basic" form of the SD/MMC memory cards and SD as a subtype or specific form of it. This is of course a simplification, as both specifications evolved in parallel after their initial introduction.

The major "improvement" of SD over MMC initially was actually the inclusion of Digital Rights Management features to the specification, to placate music suppliers' concerns about piracy, and so encourage SD cards as a possible music distribution medium. (Didn't exactly work out as expected.)

The SD card was also specified to be a bit thicker than MMC, so MMC found its niche in use cases where DRM was not required and thinness was important.

When you access a SD/MMC card using a USB-based card reader, it will usually appear as `/dev/sdX` device, since the *reader* is being accessed with a SCSI-like protocol. But when a reader device that allows direct access to the "native" SD/MMC interface, a `/dev/mmcblkN` device name is used.

With a `/dev/mmcblkN` device, you will be able to use the low-level tools of the `mmc-utils` package and will be able to use some card functions that are not available with (most?) card readers that present a `/dev/sdX` device.

The internal memory of openwrt devices (and similar) is often specifically an **eMMC**: [a MMC card controller and memory card packaged as a single permanently soldered chip.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MultiMediaCard#eMMC)

Comment: Great answer… thanks.  Answered all of my question and more.